# Execute MySQL-Command with double quote from PowerShell

Tags: mysql, powershell

I don't know how to execute a MySQL-Command from PowerShell 4.0 with double quotation mark

The SQL-Query:

```
$SqlQuery = @"
USE joomla; UPDATE jml_shoutbox SET msg = "$msg_neu" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
"@
```

The message to insert:

```
$msg_neu = "Dies ist ein <a href="www.google.de">Link</a> ok?"
```

tried also this:

```
$msg_neu = 'Dies ist ein <a href="www.google.de">Link</a> ok?'
```

and this:

```
$msg_neu = "Dies ist ein <a href=`"www.google.de`">Link</a> ok?"
```

The command from PowerShell:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root -ppassword -e $SqlQuery
```

When I execute that from PS I get the following:

> C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root -ppassword -e $SqlQuery Warning:
>   Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
>   C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.11, for Win32
>   (x86) Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All
>   rights reserved.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
>   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.
>
> Usage: C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe [OPTIONS] [database]   -?, --help 
>   Display this help and exit.   -I, --help          Synonym for -?
>   ...

But when I do that directly on mysql> it works fine:

```
UPDATE jml_shoutbox SET msg = 'Dies ist ein <a href="www.google.de">Link</a> ok?' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Do someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$msg_neu = 'Dies ist ein <a href="www.google.de">Link</a> ok?'

$SqlQuery = @"
  USE joomla; UPDATE jml_shoutbox SET msg = '$msg_neu' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
"@
```

Comment: Does MySQL make a distinction between single and double quotes? If yes, will this not change the semantics of the query? Would it not be better to escape the double quotes? So the semantics are preserved? Also, adding a small comment explaining your answer would be helpful to beginners.

Comment: SQL strings use single quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

But after I executed the command, the value of the field in the databse is:

`Dies ist ein <a href=www.google.de>Link</a> ok?`

So, without qoutes...

Comment: I just tried the proposed solution and it works for me! A small side-note: Manually constructing your SQL strings is dangerous (SQL injections) and error-prone (unexpected bugs). However, I don't think the `mysql.exe` command allows you to specify query place-holders. So you need sanitize your string before running the query. This only applies for strings generated by user-input though.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to mask the double quotes too!